# iTunes Store operation failed: Invalid image path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots, ci-server

Using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2
When i try to upload the app to the app store by archiving the app and uploading it, it works fine.
But when i try to do it using Xcode bots (Xcode CI server) i get the below error described in the screenshot:

```
Invalid image path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'
```

[image: iTunes operation failed]

I already tried:

- Replace App icons and made sure the naming conventions are correct (though i don't think it matters) and dimensions are correct as well.
- Double checked that App Icons is part of the target.
- In the target, App Icons and launch image section, made sure that AppIcon is selected in App icons source.

Now if there is an issue with App icons how come it works fine when uploading through local Xcode.

What else i can do?